# Disable code inspection in SharpDevelop

Tags: sharpdevelop, code-inspection

How can I disable the code inspection in SharpDevelop 5.1? It annoys me as hell and slows down typing speed due to constant code checks. There is a checkbox in Tools - Options - Coding - C# - Code inspection, but it is read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is not currently possible to disable code analysis. Looking at the SharpDevelop source code that check box does not do anything even if it was enabled. So your options are:

1. Disable the C# addin. Which will break C# completely.
2. Disable all the analysis rules.
3. Build SharpDevelop from source and stop the IssueManager from running.
4. File a [bug](https://github.com/icsharpcode/sharpdevelop/issues) and wait for someone from the SharpDevelop team to fix the bug.
5. Switch to SharpDevelop 4